# How to make a Category parent link not cliquable and just the subcatgories cliquables M2

Tags: magento2, category

I have a category with id =41 and have 2 child i want to see the parent category and her child but just make the parent category link not cliquable any idea please and thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at this https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Remove-links-to-top-categories-in-menu/m-p/77074#M2904
if that is what you want

Comment: thanks for your replay just one question i want to remove the cliquable link for specific category

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a custom module to override Template.php. See below for the module. One should not make changes in the vendor directory.

> app/code/[vendor]/[module]/Block/Html/Topmenu.php

```
<?php
namespace [vendor]\[module]\Block\Html;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\NodeFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Data\TreeFactory;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

/**
* Html page top menu block
*
* @api
* @since 100.0.2
*/
class Topmenu extends Template implements IdentityInterface
{
/**
 * Cache identities
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $identities = [];

/**
 * Top menu data tree
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node
 */
protected $_menu;

/**
 * @var NodeFactory
 */
private $nodeFactory;

/**
 * @var TreeFactory
 */
private $treeFactory;

/**
 * @param Template\Context $context
 * @param NodeFactory $nodeFactory
 * @param TreeFactory $treeFactory
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    Template\Context $context,
    NodeFactory $nodeFactory,
    TreeFactory $treeFactory,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->nodeFactory = $nodeFactory;
    $this->treeFactory = $treeFactory;
}

/**
 * Get block cache life time
 *
 * @return int
 * @since 100.1.0
 */
protected function getCacheLifetime()
{
    return parent::getCacheLifetime() ?: 3600;
}

/**
 * Get top menu html
 *
 * @param string $outermostClass
 * @param string $childrenWrapClass
 * @param int $limit
 * @return string
 */
public function getHtml($outermostClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '', $limit = 0)
{
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
        'page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before',
        ['menu' => $this->getMenu(), 'block' => $this, 'request' => $this->getRequest()]
    );

    $this->getMenu()->setOutermostClass($outermostClass);
    $this->getMenu()->setChildrenWrapClass($childrenWrapClass);

    $html = $this->_getHtml($this->getMenu(), $childrenWrapClass, $limit);

    $transportObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(['html' => $html]);
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
        'page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_after',
        ['menu' => $this->getMenu(), 'transportObject' => $transportObject]
    );
    $html = $transportObject->getHtml();
    return $html;
}

/**
 * Count All Subnavigation Items
 *
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Model\Menu $items
 * @return int
 */
protected function _countItems($items)
{
    $total = $items->count();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        /** @var $item \Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Item */
        if ($item->hasChildren()) {
            $total += $this->_countItems($item->getChildren());
        }
    }
    return $total;
}

/**
 * Building Array with Column Brake Stops
 *
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Model\Menu $items
 * @param int $limit
 * @return array|void
 *
 * @todo: Add Depth Level limit, and better logic for columns
 */
protected function _columnBrake($items, $limit)
{
    $total = $this->_countItems($items);
    if ($total <= $limit) {
        return;
    }

    $result[] = ['total' => $total, 'max' => (int)ceil($total / ceil($total / $limit))];

    $count = 0;
    $firstCol = true;

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $place = $this->_countItems($item->getChildren()) + 1;
        $count += $place;

        if ($place >= $limit) {
            $colbrake = !$firstCol;
            $count = 0;
        } elseif ($count >= $limit) {
            $colbrake = !$firstCol;
            $count = $place;
        } else {
            $colbrake = false;
        }

        $result[] = ['place' => $place, 'colbrake' => $colbrake];

        $firstCol = false;
    }

    return $result;
}

/**
 * Add sub menu HTML code for current menu item
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $child
 * @param string $childLevel
 * @param string $childrenWrapClass
 * @param int $limit
 * @return string HTML code
 */
protected function _addSubMenu($child, $childLevel, $childrenWrapClass, $limit)
{
    $html = '';
    if (!$child->hasChildren()) {
        return $html;
    }

    $colStops = [];
    if ($childLevel == 0 && $limit) {
        $colStops = $this->_columnBrake($child->getChildren(), $limit);
    }

    $html .= '<ul class="level' . $childLevel . ' ' . $childrenWrapClass . '">';
    $html .= $this->_getHtml($child, $childrenWrapClass, $limit, $colStops);
    $html .= '</ul>';

    return $html;
}

/**
 * Recursively generates top menu html from data that is specified in $menuTree
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menuTree
 * @param string $childrenWrapClass
 * @param int $limit
 * @param array $colBrakes
 * @return string
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
 */
protected function _getHtml(
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menuTree,
    $childrenWrapClass,
    $limit,
    $colBrakes = []
) {
    $html = '';

    $children = $menuTree->getChildren();
    $parentLevel = $menuTree->getLevel();
    $childLevel = $parentLevel === null ? 0 : $parentLevel + 1;

    $counter = 1;
    $itemPosition = 1;
    $childrenCount = $children->count();

    $parentPositionClass = $menuTree->getPositionClass();
    $itemPositionClassPrefix = $parentPositionClass ? $parentPositionClass . '-' : 'nav-';

    foreach ($children as $child) {
        $child->setLevel($childLevel);
        $child->setIsFirst($counter == 1);
        $child->setIsLast($counter == $childrenCount);
        $child->setPositionClass($itemPositionClassPrefix . $counter);

        $outermostClassCode = '';
        $outermostClass = $menuTree->getOutermostClass();

        if ($childLevel == 0 && $outermostClass) {
            $outermostClassCode = ' class="' . $outermostClass . '" ';
            $child->setClass($outermostClass);
        }

        if (count($colBrakes) && $colBrakes[$counter]['colbrake']) {
            $html .= '</ul></li><li class="column"><ul>';
        }

        $html .= '<li ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . '>';
        if($child->getId() != 'category-node-41'){
            $html .= '<a data-test="'.$child->getLevel().'" href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>'
                . $this->escapeHtml($child->getName())
                . '</span></a>' . $this->_addSubMenu(
                    $child,
                    $childLevel,
                    $childrenWrapClass,
                    $limit
                ) . '</li>';
        }else{
            $html .= '<a href="javascript&colon;void(0)" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>'
                . $this->escapeHtml($child->getName())
                . '</span></a>' . $this->_addSubMenu(
                    $child,
                    $childLevel,
                    $childrenWrapClass,
                    $limit
                ) . '</li>';
        }
        $itemPosition++;
        $counter++;
    }

    if (count($colBrakes) && $limit) {
        $html = '<li class="column"><ul>' . $html . '</ul></li>';
    }

    return $html;
}

/**
 * Generates string with all attributes that should be present in menu item element
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $item
 * @return string
 */
protected function _getRenderedMenuItemAttributes(\Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $item)
{
    $html = '';
    $attributes = $this->_getMenuItemAttributes($item);
    foreach ($attributes as $attributeName => $attributeValue) {
        $html .= ' ' . $attributeName . '="' . str_replace('"', '\"', $attributeValue) . '"';
    }
    return $html;
}

/**
 * Returns array of menu item's attributes
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $item
 * @return array
 */
protected function _getMenuItemAttributes(\Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $item)
{
    $menuItemClasses = $this->_getMenuItemClasses($item);
    return ['class' => implode(' ', $menuItemClasses)];
}

/**
 * Returns array of menu item's classes
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $item
 * @return array
 */
protected function _getMenuItemClasses(\Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $item)
{
    $classes = [];

    $classes[] = 'level' . $item->getLevel();
    $classes[] = $item->getPositionClass();

    if ($item->getIsCategory()) {
        $classes[] = 'category-item';
    }

    if ($item->getIsFirst()) {
        $classes[] = 'first';
    }

    if ($item->getIsActive()) {
        $classes[] = 'active';
    } elseif ($item->getHasActive()) {
        $classes[] = 'has-active';
    }

    if ($item->getIsLast()) {
        $classes[] = 'last';
    }

    if ($item->getClass()) {
        $classes[] = $item->getClass();
    }

    if ($item->hasChildren()) {
        $classes[] = 'parent';
    }

    return $classes;
}

/**
 * Add identity
 *
 * @param string|array $identity
 * @return void
 */
public function addIdentity($identity)
{
    if (!in_array($identity, $this->identities)) {
        $this->identities[] = $identity;
    }
}

/**
 * Get identities
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getIdentities()
{
    return $this->identities;
}

/**
 * Get cache key informative items
 *
 * @return array
 * @since 100.1.0
 */
public function getCacheKeyInfo()
{
    $keyInfo = parent::getCacheKeyInfo();
    $keyInfo[] = $this->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_query' => '']);
    return $keyInfo;
}

/**
 * Get tags array for saving cache
 *
 * @return array
 * @since 100.1.0
 */
protected function getCacheTags()
{
    return array_merge(parent::getCacheTags(), $this->getIdentities());
}

/**
 * Get menu object.
 *
 * Creates \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node root node object.
 * The creation logic was moved from class constructor into separate method.
 *
 * @return Node
 * @since 100.1.0
 */
public function getMenu()
{
    if (!$this->_menu) {
        $this->_menu = $this->nodeFactory->create(
            [
                'data' => [],
                'idField' => 'root',
                'tree' => $this->treeFactory->create()
            ]
        );
    }
    return $this->_menu;
}
}
```

> app/code/[vendor]/[module]/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="[vendor]_[module]" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

> app/code/[vendor]/[module]/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"> 
    <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" type="[vendor]\[module]\Block\Html\Topmenu" /> 
</config>
```

> app/code/[vendor]/[module]/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '[vendor]_[module]',
    __DIR__
);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Override vendor/magento/module-theme/Block/Html/Topmenu.php** in your custom module.

Take a look at this https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Remove-links-to-top-categories-in-menu/m-p/77074#M2904

It's the same code. Just change the if condition. For me category `id is 20` so `if($child->getId() != 'category-node-20'){...}`. Place your category id instead of 20

**vendor/magento/module-theme/Block/Html/Topmenu.php**

```
protected function _getHtml(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menuTree,
        $childrenWrapClass,
        $limit,
        $colBrakes = []
    ) {
        $html = '';

        $children = $menuTree->getChildren();
        $parentLevel = $menuTree->getLevel();
        $childLevel = $parentLevel === null ? 0 : $parentLevel + 1;

        $counter = 1;
        $itemPosition = 1;
        $childrenCount = $children->count();

        $parentPositionClass = $menuTree->getPositionClass();
        $itemPositionClassPrefix = $parentPositionClass ? $parentPositionClass . '-' : 'nav-';

        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $child->setLevel($childLevel);
            $child->setIsFirst($counter == 1);
            $child->setIsLast($counter == $childrenCount);
            $child->setPositionClass($itemPositionClassPrefix . $counter);

            $outermostClassCode = '';
            $outermostClass = $menuTree->getOutermostClass();

            if ($childLevel == 0 && $outermostClass) {
                $outermostClassCode = ' class="' . $outermostClass . '" ';
                $child->setClass($outermostClass);
            }

            if (count($colBrakes) && $colBrakes[$counter]['colbrake']) {
                $html .= '</ul></li><li class="column"><ul>';
            }

            $html .= '<li ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . '>';
            if($child->getId() != 'category-node-20'){
            $html .= '<a data-test="'.$child->getLevel().'" href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>'
                . $this->escapeHtml($child->getName())
                . '</span></a>' . $this->_addSubMenu(
                    $child,
                    $childLevel,
                    $childrenWrapClass,
                    $limit
                ) . '</li>';
            }else{
            $html .= '<a href="javascript&colon;void(0)" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>'
                . $this->escapeHtml($child->getName())
                . '</span></a>' . $this->_addSubMenu(
                    $child,
                    $childLevel,
                    $childrenWrapClass,
                    $limit
                ) . '</li>';
            }
            $itemPosition++;
            $counter++;
        }

        if (count($colBrakes) && $limit) {
            $html = '<li class="column"><ul>' . $html . '</ul></li>';
        }

        return $html;
    }
```

Comment: ok thanks a lot i will check this solution :)

Comment: Ok. And as @MartinE is saying changing core files is not a good idea. I thought you already knew so just posted solution for your problem.